# How do I add value to a column?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm using MongoDB 2.6.

What would be the equivalent of this SQL query in Mongo using find()?

```
select (a * 2) as a from test
```

I've tried

```
db.test.find({}, {a: { $mul: 2 }, _id: 0})
```

but no luck.

Comment: Just curious what is the point of doing this? Why can not you just take the value and multiply on application layer?

Comment: For example it could be a*b instead of a*2. Well, I understand, that everything could be made on app layer, but if you think that way you can end up with just "find()" on db layer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the `aggregation framework` is more powerful, if your task doesn't need records to be `pipelined through one or more operations`, and is as simple as the example you have cited, You could make use of the `map()` function:

> Applies function to each document visited by the cursor and collects
>   the return values from successive application into an array.

as follows,

```
 db.test.find().map(function(doc) {return doc.a*2});
 o/p: [ 2, 6 ]
```

or to get a document for each row:

```
 db.test.find().map(function(doc) {return {"a":doc.a*2}});
 o/p: [ { "a" : 2 }, { "a" : 6 } ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I wonder if `map()` is more efficient than aggregation or not?

Comment: @Nick The aggregation framework is for much more than "grouping". And basically put, if your application server is less powerful than your database server (which is usually the case) then processing results in code is not more efficient.

Comment: @Nick i agree with Neil here. I suggested you this solution since it involved lesser operations than the aggregation framework would have performed, which is what your problem demanded.

Answer (score 1):

The [**`$mul`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/mul/) operator is only used with [`.update()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) and like methods to permanently update the data. it is one of several [update operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update-field/) and therefore has no place in a query.

What you want is something that alters the document on projection. For this you use the [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "a": { "$multiply": [ "$a", 2 ] }
    }}
])
```

The [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) pipeline stage is basically a more powerful method of basic projection. Here the [**`$multiply`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/multiply/) operator is applied in order to calculate your result.

Also look at the [SQL to aggregation mapping](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) page in the documentation for other examples of common SQL operations in MongoDB.

Comment: Thanks! I've read that I can use aggregation, but I thought that there should be an easier way :)

Comment: @Nick. It's the only way to alter the structure that is returned from the original. Anything else is "post processing". So MongoDB is not actually returning the result, but your code is altering it. There is no more overhead in the above operation than any "field projection" you can do with find.